# Custom NgRx Action seems to be not working in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to create a simple application to better understand how NgRx works. For that i have developed the following code. But it is not working as expected.

My Action.ts:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Employee } from '../Employee.model';

export const ADD_EMPLOYEE = 'ADD_EMPLOYEE';
export const EDIT_EMPLOYEE = 'EDIT_EMPLOYEE';


export class AddEmployee implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_EMPLOYEE;
    constructor(public payload: Employee){}
}

export class EditEmployee implements Action {
    readonly type = EDIT_EMPLOYEE;
    // constructor(public payload: Employee){}
}

export type EmployeeAction = EditEmployee | AddEmployee;
```

My reducer.ts

```
import * as EmployeeActions from './employee.actions';

const initialState = {
    states: [
        {name: 'Arizona', code: 'Arizona'},
        {name: 'California', value: 'California'},
        {name: 'Florida', code: 'Florida'},
        {name: 'Ohio', code: 'Ohio'},
        {name: 'Washington', code: 'Washington'}
    ],
    
};
export function employeeReducer (state = initialState, action: EmployeeActions.EmployeeAction) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case EmployeeActions.ADD_EMPLOYEE:
            console.log("Employee reducer called: ", action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                
            };
        default:
            return state;

    }
}
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
.....

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({employeeStoreReducer: employeeReducer})
  ],
```

at this point i am getting the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type '(state: { states: ({ name: string; code: string; value?: undefined; } | { name: string; value: string; code?: undefined; })[]; } | undefined, action: EmployeeAction) => { states: ({ name: string; code: string; value?: undefined; } | { ...; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<{ states: ({ name: string; code: string; value?: undefined; } | { name: string; value: string; code?: undefined; })[]; }, Action>'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'EmployeeAction'.
      Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action' but required in type 'AddEmployee'.

36     StoreModule.forRoot({employeeStoreReducer: employeeReducer}),
                           
  src/app/employee/store/employee.actions.ts:10:17
    10     constructor(public payload: Employee){}

    'payload' is declared here.
```

But if i change **action: EmployeeActions.EmployeeAction** to **action: Action** it starts working. But in this case i cannot send any payload.
Please help in resolving the issue and also let me know the reason for this. I can share more code if needed. I am using angular version 11.1.2, ngrx version 11.0.1. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this project is using Angular/NGRX v11.x, and you are attempting to learn modern techniques with NGRX, I would discard the pattern you are using and use the factory functions provided by the library.

For example:

*Action File*

```
export const addEmployee = createAction(
  ADD_EMPLOYEE, 
  props<{payload: Employee}>()
);
export const editEmployee = createAction(
  EDIT_EMPLOYEE, 
  props<{payload: Employee}>()
);
```

*Reducer File*

```
export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  
  on(EmployeeActions.addEmployee, (state, { payload }) => {
    console.log("Employee Reducer Called")
    return {
       ...state, //Insert Add Logic here
    };
  }),

  on(EmployeeActions.editEmployee, (state, { payload }) => {
    console.log("Employee Reducer Called")
    return {
       ...state, //Insert Edit Logic here
    };
  }),
);
```

The NGRX Docs show this effectively: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestion. I have changed the code accordingly.  I was facing the same error with the updated syntax as well. After i disabled "scrtict" mode to false in tsconfig.json file.it started working fine. My old code is also running fine after the same. Can you please let me know if disabling the scrict mode is acceptable for PROD build.

Comment: Can you show your code with the new structure?

Comment: Here is my full app code - https://github.com/pallabsarkar/utility.git

Comment: This looks different than the project above, in that it is dealing with budgets and not employees.  Where are you getting the type error?  Also - I'd be wary using your pattern with nested objects.  Your reducer is just shuffling pointers to Income objects (in the array), so you could end up changing the store accidentally in your UI.  I'd recommend looking up NGRX Entity, it will save you a lot of work.

Comment: sorry for sharing different project. actually i am trying with different ideas with NgRx and this is the latest i had. When changing the "strict" property in tsconfig.json file from "false" to "true" i am getting the error. Thanks for the suggestion. I will take a look at the NgRx entity surely.

Answer (score 0):

I think since you're using a modern version of `ngrx` the second argument has interface of `Action`.

You should create your reducer and actions as [this](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#creating-the-reducer-function). The actions are slightly above it.